# Machine learning for VLSI floorplanning tool

Tags: machine-learning

I have an educational assignment to make an VLSI floor-planning tool.

Can I use machine learning in some part of the algorithm? For example, I was reading the book Algorithms for VLSI Physical Design Automation by Naveed Sherwani, and here's a quote from there:

> Initial estimate on the set of feasible
>   alternatives for a block can be made by statistical means, i.e., by estimating
>   the expected area requirement of the block.

Can I use ML for that? Or there's no sense in doing so?
If no, is there some part where I can use ML?

Thanks in advance.